# wpa_passphrase must be 8..63 characters

Tags: networking, security, wifi, wpa

I'd like to connect to wireless network via command line in Linux.
When doing it I've stuck with this issue:

```
 $ wpa_passphrase NETWORK_SSID NETWORK_PASSWORD
 Passphrase must be 8..63 characters
```

The NETWORK_PASSWORD has only five characters.

Via smartphone there is no problem with connection. Could you help me to
solve this?

Comment: wpa_passphrase is not used to connect to a wlan. See http://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_passphrase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wpa_passphrase` is used for generating keys for automatic WPA connections. If you want a manual one time from the command line setup use `iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORK_ID key WIRELESS_KEY`

Comment: This ends with error `sudo iwconfig eth1 essid NETW_ID key PASSWD
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
    invalid argument "PASSWD".

Comment: eth1 is a strange designation for a wireless card. You should also be replacing "PASSWD" with your wireless access key/password.

Comment: Yes it strange, but this is not a main problem. Naturally, I have there a password, but I'm not going to share it here.

Comment: Ahh OK. Sometimes people just cut and paste my code, so I had to ask. Does `iwconfig eth1` show that eth1 has wireless extensions? You can find answers to your error here: http://superuser.com/questions/42460/can-you-explain-how-to-understand-what-the-iwconfig-command-displays-in-ubuntu

Comment: This is really useful link, but don't see what is wrong. [Here](http://pastebin.com/bBWSyc3T) is iwconfig output.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot input less than 8 ASCII character as it is defined on 802.11 standard**

What you can do is to use more than 8 ASCII character.

You can also see the protocol's implementation on the source code of the [wpa_passphrase](https://github.com/gxk/hostap/blob/master/wpa_supplicant/wpa_passphrase.c)

```
if (os_strlen(passphrase) < 8 || os_strlen(passphrase) > 63) {
        printf("Passphrase must be 8..63 characters\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Btw, `wpa_passphrase` is used to generate password phrase, not to connect a WLAN. And the passphrase is used on `wpa_supplicant.conf` which is a tool that I would recommend you to use, for more info click on`[wpa_supplicant][1]`.

Alternatively you can use `iw` tool or the deprecated `iwconfig`. However, these two tools work for only WEP encryption that is phasing out (and of course open network (without encryption)). You can not connect to an AP that use WPA or WPA2 encryption